# facebook application id 

Tags: iphone

hi i am using the following app id to upload images to Facebook using Facebook graph api

//Facebook Application ID

NSString *client_id = @"130902823636657";

after generating client id , up to what time we can use that id and is there any expiration time for that client id?

can any any one provide me these details .......

thanks in advance

Comment: This is one of the most confusing questions I've ever seen on S.O.  Would it be possible to edit your post to be more concise about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you created appliction on facebook and get the ClientID/ APPId and screte key,  there is no expiration time for this until and unless you ask to reset these keys or delete the app.